# Move concept in the C++ standard

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I'm curious where description of moving objects is in the C++ ISO document. I've seen only informations about rvalue reference, move constructor, move assignment operator and their syntax. I couldn't find a official reason why "move" is described as moving resource between objects.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What're you looking for exactly? Note that the standard isn't a tutorial, it's not going to have a description of what move semantics is - just what effects various language constructs have (like what a move constructor is, when it's called, etc.)

Comment: I've found this [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf). I think that is official documentation

Comment: That's the closest thing to the C++17 standard, yes, but it doesn't answer my question for you about your question.

Comment: I'm not looking for anything now. I've received an answer. I've not knew a phrase "move semantics". If I had knew it before I would have found it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm:

> Move semantics is mostly about performance optimization: the ability to move an expensive object from one address in memory to another, while pilfering resources of the source in order to construct the target with minimum expense.
>
> Move semantics already exists in the current language and library to a certain extent:
>
> - copy constructor elision in some contexts
> - auto_ptr "copy"
> - list::splice
> - swap on containers
>
> All of these operations involve transferring resources from one object (location) to another (at least conceptually). What is lacking is uniform syntax and semantics to enable generic code to move arbitrary objects (just as generic code today can copy arbitrary objects). There are several places in the standard library that would greatly benefit from the ability to move objects instead of copy them (to be discussed in depth below).

Comment: @Patrycjerz it's not really a language feature, it's a meta feature , a design element, I suppose (someone may put finger on more proper definition). Move semantics predate C++ by decades